# MySQL query not fetching results (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, web

I have the following script with an SQL problem which is not working.

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "Freepaste";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

echo $user."  ".$pass;

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where users.username= ? AND users.password = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $user, $pass);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);;

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<br>id: " . $row["username"]." Password ".$row["password"]. "<br>";
    }
} 
else {
    echo "<br>0 results <br>";
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

The statement without the "where" clause gets me all the results, so I know the keys are right. Also, I ran the query in MySQL and it is working fine. I tried adding **""** to *$user* and *$pass*, still not working. I checked the names in HTML, they are correct too. What am I missing?

Here's the link to the HTML:
http://pastebin.com/CWLuafVq

Comment: Posted the entire code. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the quotes (although you are saying you tried) i think it should have worked. Your query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM users where users.username='$user' AND users.password='$pass'
```

Your query is vulnerable to SQL injection and in order to avoid it (and avoid hassle like requiring quotes in SQL statement), you should use PreparedStatement.

Comment: I have prepared the statement, just left it out for better readability.
The single quotes don't work either.

Comment: Sorry of i offended you. i understood my mistake and posted the entire code. Please, I am a novice, but not a liar. 
What i meant to say was that I know that single quotes should work, but they aren't. The kind of bugs that make life difficult.

Comment: @goelakash I think, then, that you do not understand what prepared statements are, as there is still not one in your question. Check the link in the answer I have given.

Comment: yes, i saw that and replaced that part of the code. The form is able to get $user and $pass, but the query is not working. It works in phpMyAdmin, so there's no problem there. The bug is PHP.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, when your variables are put into the sql query, it ends up looking like this `WHERE users.username=goelakash AN...`. Without quotes around username and password, mysql is going to think you're comparing two columns.

What your query needs to look like is this.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users where users.username=\"$user\" AND users.password=\"$pass\"";
```

Do yourself a huge favor, and [put mysqli_error() calls](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) after your calls to `mysqli_query()`. These will tell you exactly what mysql is crying about.

It is also worth noting that your queries are open to sql injection and you should take a look at [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to mitigate that.

Answer (score 1):

For your example, you just need to put single quotes around $user and $pass in the query.

BUT!!!!!! Your query is open to SQL injection. You should change the way you write queries. Use bound parameters instead, then you can almost forget about that issue.

Example:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where users.username= ? AND users.password = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $user, $pass);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) for more information

Answer (score 1):

make sure your database password is 'root'? If yes then follow the query string

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.username='$user' AND users.password='$pass'";
```

just replace it. I think it will work fine :)